# Передача TreeMap в AsyncTask

Tags: android

Есть TreeMap:

```
TreeMap<String,String> tmap = new TreeMap<>();
tmap.put("Value_1", "Value");

getAccessPing getPing = new getAccessPing();
getPing.execute(tmap);
```

Есть AsyncTask

```
class getAccessPing extends AsyncTask <TreeMap ,String,Objects>
{

    @Override
    protected Objects doInBackground(TreeMap... f)
    {
        Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> set = f.entrySet();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Понятное дело что так в doInBackground TreeMap не будет передан. Т.к doInBackground принимает только массивы. Как правильно передать TreeMap ?

Comment: можете оформить часть вашего вопроса как ответ, если вас всё устраивает, и получить за это ачивку.

Comment: Да я бы с удовольствием, но не могу понять как.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так, работает как и задумывалось:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> set;
@Override
protected Objects doInBackground(TreeMap... f)
{
    for(TreeMap s : f)
    {
        set = s.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> me : set)
        {
            publishProgress(me.getKey() +"-"+ me.getValue());
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```